# Weird HTML Issue. Text size gets small when clicking link

Tags: html, css

Check out this website for my customer: http://www.jenkagroup.com on a a Android mobile device.

When clicking the "Click Here" link, the whole line of text gets small and it does nothing. Clicking it again, then the link works.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

It doesn't seem to happen in Safari or on any desktop PC browser. Just on Android Chrome viewed on a smaller size screen (mobile).

Any ideas?

Comment: It also happens in Desktop Chrome when viewing in debug console with view mode of "Galaxy S5"

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this rule to the head of your site:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

I was able to trigger it in chrome, but it also stopped once I added this rule. It is likely due to the way that devices render information for different sized screens. For reference, check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: I just added that line to the head and it made no difference.

Comment: Did you add it to that site? I am not seeing it in the console. Also be sure to clear the cache on your android device, or open it in a private/anonymous window

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry I added it to the wrong site. I added it now and it works, however now the page does not scale to the device width like it used to.  But at least it works now. That doesn't quite explain the behavior though, I  think this is just a band-aid fix?

Comment: @JasonRoozee In a way, this is a band aid fix. Because the site isn't setup to be responsive and without the viewport tag, browsers decide what they think should happen, which is why you're seeing inconsistent results. The viewport meta tag sets a default for all browsers. It shouldn't take you too long to refactor the site css to be responsive. It'd just be adding a bunch of media queries at certain breakpoints, and setting the containers widths to something like 100%.